# How to force show text selection controls?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to show text selection controls on:

```
setState( () {
  textController.selection = TextSelection(baseOffset: 0, extentOffset: textController.text.length);
});
```

But it did not appear on the screen. So, how to force flutter show the cut/copy/paste menu?

Comment: similar issue on [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34013)

Answer (score -1):

I hope it helps you.
You can use Selectable Widget. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSU3ZXOs6hc&list=PLjxrf2q8roU23XGwz3Km7sQZFTdB996iG&index=56

#### Second suggestion

When I test with below code, it works well.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "App",
      theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.amber),
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController(text: 'Kevin A');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Title",
      theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.amber),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: TextField(
            controller: controller,
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            controller.selection = new TextSelection(
              baseOffset: 0,
              extentOffset: controller.text.length,
            );
            showMenu(
              context: context,
              // TODO: Position dynamically based on cursor or textfield
              position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(0.0, 300.0, 300.0, 0.0),
              items: [
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      // TODO: Dynamic items / handle click
                      PopupMenuItem(
                        child: Text(
                          "Paste",
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .body2
                              .copyWith(color: Colors.red),
                        ),
                      ),
                      PopupMenuItem(
                        child: Text("Select All"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.navigation),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: no, I need to do it with TextEditingController and TextField